# Faire « des accroires » : l'emploi comme nom ?

Tags: expressions, québec, infinitif, substantivation

On a déjà entendu (au Québec) l'*accroire* employé comme nom masculin basé sur l'infinitif du verbe [accroire](http://larousse.fr/dictionnaires/francais/accroire/559?q=accroire#558) pour la *chose qu'on fait accroire*, la chose qu'on sait ne pas être vraie ; surtout en locution avec *faire* (des). On semble avoir déjà eu le substantif en France aussi :

[image]

<sup>[*Französisches Etymologisches Wörterbuch*](https://apps.atilf.fr/lecteurFEW/index.php/page/lire/e/1993) (FEW), *Le dictionnaire étymologique et historique du galloroman* (français et dialectes d’oïl, francoprovençal, occitan, gascon), vol. 2 (C Q K), 1305b, *accredere* (Atilf).</sup>

Par ailleurs on a le [*faire accroire*](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/accroire) substantivé (« Mais moi je suis Mara Vercors qui n'aime pas l'injustice et le faire accroire. » P. Claudel, au *TLFi*), assurément dans les parages. [Généralement](http://bdl.oqlf.gouv.qc.ca/bdl/gabarit_bdl.asp?id=4220), un nom de forme simple dérivé d'un infinitif prend la marque du pluriel le cas échéant (BDL, par ex. des plaisirs, du verbe *plaisir* en [ancien français](http://www.cnrtl.fr/etymologie/plaisir), qu'on ne reconnaît sans doute plus aujourd'hui).

---

- Peut-on étayer de manière plus *crédible* (œuvre, lexique) l'emploi du nom *accroire(s)* au
  Québec ?
- En France (ou ailleurs) est-ce qu'on entend *faire des accroires* aujourd'hui en langue parlée et
  a-t-on un exemple en littérature (universelle) de l'expression ou de l'emploi en substantif (surtout au pluriel) de l'*accroire* ?

  - Autrement, comment dirait-on communément l'équivalent de l'expression *faire des accroires* (à quelqu'un), de la phrase *ce sont des accroires*, et du nom *accroire(s)* ?

Comment: Comme dit cl-r, jamais entendu en France...

Comment: Et que veut dire cette expression au Québec? Impossible de trouver un équivalent d'une expression qu'on ne comprend pas.

Comment: This doesn’t address the “nounification” (or not) of either one, but I find interesting the similarities (esp their [& their Latin roots’] spelling but also their lack of modern noun forms & imo, their general “weirdness”) between “[faire] accroire” & “accroître,” & to the extent that the “rendre plus/augmenter [what/however]” notion of “accroître” could be/have once been similar to the “Rendre plus intéressant en ajoutant des détails plus ou moins exacts” notion of “embellir” (i.e., “mensonge par embelissement/exagération”), perhaps there’s a [lost] connection that’s relevant to your inquiry.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Un complément. D'abord, la référence du *FEW* à (1784, Restif, Gohin) ; c'est que [Ferdinand Gohin](http://www.academie-francaise.fr/ferdinand-gohin) note en 1905 dans [*Les transformations de la langue française au XVIIIe siècle (1740-1789)*](https://books.google.com/books?id=y4KhhnY3sV0C&dq=%22accroires%22&hl=fr&pg=PA231#v=onepage&q=%22accroires%22&f=false) que [Restif de la Bretonne](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nicolas_Edme_Restif_de_La_Bretonne) (Bourgogne-Franche-Comté) l'aurait écrit dans son oeuvre *La Paysanne pervertie* (1784) : « De tous les accroires qu'on nous a faits. » (II, 502). Je ne peux retrouver ce passage mais trouve deux autres oeuvres du même auteur où il l'emploie :

> Vous me contez là des coccigrues, la Bonne, & vous me prenez pour une
>   Enfant, à quî l'on fait des accroires : je ne suis pas faite d'hier.
>
> [ [*Les contemporaines, ou Avantures des plus jolies femmes de l'âge
>   présent*](https://books.google.com/books?id=biBjGkc6IWcC&dq=%22accroires%22&hl=fr&pg=PA633#v=onepage&q=%22accroires%22&f=false), Nicolas-Edme Rétif de La Bretonne, 1780-1785 ]
>
> ---
>
> Bast! dit en riant Brancabanda : alons-donc ! vous voudriez me faire
>   des accroires, & me persuader que des vessies sont des lanternes.
>
> [ [*Le Nouvel Abeilard ; ou Lettres de deux amans qui ne se sont jamais
>   vus...*](https://books.google.com/books?id=OR-f5fcfjOQC&dq=r%C3%A9tif%20bretonne%20accroires&pg=PA167#v=onepage&q=r%C3%A9tif%20bretonne%20accroires&f=false), Nicolas-Edme Rétif de La Bretonne, 1778 ]

---

Dans un ouvrage de référence assez récent (2011), le [*Dictionnaire des régionalismes des îles de la Madeleine*](https://books.google.com/books?id=ryjD8fRwwbcC&lpg=PA3&dq=%22accroires%22&hl=fr&pg=PA3#v=onepage&q=%22accroires%22&f=false) (Chantal Naud), on identifie l'*accroire* pour les « *idées fausses, mensonges, imaginations erronées* » et on donne entre autres des exemples d'Anselme Chiasson ([*Le diable Frigolet*](https://books.google.com/books?id=5bHYAAAAMAAJ&dq=anselme%20chiasson%20accroires&focus=searchwithinvolume&q=accroires)) et d'Antonine Maillet : « C'est ben, que j'y dis, faut pas se faire des accrouères. » ([*La Sagouine*](https://books.google.com/books?id=R8_xAAAAMAAJ&dq=editions%3AYhmn0oFiWbAC&focus=searchwithinvolume&q=accrou%C3%A8res), 1971). Les Acadiens le connaissent assurément. Par ailleurs, dans l'oeuvre de Felix-Antoine Savard, [*Menaud, maître-draveur*](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Menaud,_ma%C3%AEtre-draveur), on trouve :

> Et, plus tard, le voyant au-dessus des autres, comme un pin de haut
>   lignage aux clochetons pleins d'azur et de rumeurs, il s'était lui,
>   Menaud, dressé tout droit dans l'orgueil de son sang, et s'était fait
>   des accroires d'avenir.
>
> Joson ferait son chemin, sa marque ...
>
> [ [*Menaud, maître-draveur*](https://books.google.com/books?id=DXvqlk3SQO8C&dq=Menaud%2C%20ma%C3%AEtre-draveur&focus=searchwithinvolume&q=accroires), [Felix-Antoine Savard](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/F%C3%A9lix-Antoine_Savard), 1937 ]

On le trouve aussi dans une œuvre plus moderne comme le théâtre de Marie Laberge : « On s'fait des accroires, on vit un bout d'temps avec, y s'écrasent, y font pus, on change d'accroire pis on fait un aut' bout. » ([*Le faucon*](https://books.google.com/books?id=abtcAAAAMAAJ&q=%22accroires%22&dq=%22accroires%22&hl=fr&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwj52PLTsNrMAhUk6oMKHR40AgE4ChDoAQgkMAE), 1991). Ou dans [*La traversée de la ville*](https://books.google.com/books?id=DKsLAQAAMAAJ&dq=accroires%20michel%20tremblay&focus=searchwithinvolume&q=accroires), par exemple, chez Michel Tremblay (2008) : « Depuis que les hommes font des accroires aux femmes, que les femmes s'arragent pour les croire. »

---

Ça ressemble beaucoup à *raconter des [histoires](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/academie9/histoires)* (Fam. et péj. Le plus souvent au pluriel. Récit mensonger, propos fallacieux. *Je ne crois pas un mot de vos histoires. Cet enfant raconte des histoires. Ils ont inventé toute cette histoire.*, Ac. 9) , ou des [balivernes](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/baliverne). L'usage en est parfaitement naturel pour moi (Québec, sud-ouest), surtout avec *se faire/faire/c[e n']est rien que des*.

Comment: C'est vrai. Au nominal "des histoires" est une bien meilleure définition que ce que je suggérais.

Answer (score 4):

***[Accroire](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=accroire&year_start=1400&year_end=2016&corpus=19&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Caccroire%3B%2Cc0)*** est ancien, il est tombé en désuétude

***[Accroires](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=accroires&year_start=1500&year_end=2008&corpus=19&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Caccroires%3B%2Cc0#t1%3B%2Caccroires%3B%2Cc1)***, mot récent inconnu de *[Grammalecte](http://www.dicollecte.org/grammalecte/)*, ne fait pas partie du vocabulaire parlé en France

Liste d'*[exemples **québécois**](https://www.google.fr/search?q=%22accroires%22&tbm=bks&lr=lang_fr&gws_rd=cr&ei=nXU1V53TM8GysgG37L_ABQ)* d'*accroire**s***

---

Familièrement on dit « [*Tu me racontes des craques*](https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/raconter_des_craques) » pour « Tu veux me faire accroire que ... »

Answer (score 3):

Québécois ici. Personellement, n'ai jamais entendu ce mot employé comme nom. Malgré tout, les exemples ne manquent pas rien que sur le site de *La Presse*. C'est surtout dans les citations ou les commentaires, donc clairement perçu comme un usage oral (remarquez d'ailleurs les guillementsdans certains examples):

- [Les Gabrielle de Laval - et celles de Montréal, aussi - ont toutes un point en commun : elles se **font des «accroires»**.](http://plus.lapresse.ca/screens/491c-d88c-519e3c33-b2fd-50a4ac1c606a%7C_0.html)
- [[...]  accusant son prédécesseur péquiste, Réjean Hébert, d'avoir «**fait des accroires** du père Noël» en mettant sur la table «un projet [le livre blanc sur l'assurance autonomie] non financé».](http://www.lapresse.ca/le-soleil/actualites/sante/201604/13/01-4970814-barrette-sengage-a-investir-dans-les-soins-a-domicile-un-jour.php)
- [Le père disait que ça existait pas Mourial, que c’était **juste des accroires**…](http://blogues.lapresse.ca/desiront/2010/04/20/montreal-a-vos-risques-et-perils/)
- [On ne se **fait pas trop d'accroires**.](http://www.lapresse.ca/le-nouvelliste/arts/week-end/201003/19/01-4262243-tricot-machine-na-pas-ete-change-par-le-succes.php)
- [Pouvez vous **faire toutes les «accroires»** que vous voulez, [...]](http://blogues.lapresse.ca/hetu/2015/02/11/scott-walker-et-levolution/)

Moi j'aurais tendence à dire *tu me niaises* ou *t'essaye de me passer un sapin*. Faires des accroires, ce n'est absolument pas usage qui me vient naturellement.

Comment: +1 Rien que pour "t'essayes de me passer un sapin".

Comment: Merci ! Oui j'ai remarqué les guillemets pour le registre etc.. On ne semble pas toujours assumer l'emploi, ou on corrige ou je ne sais trop. J'ai trouvé aussi directement à l'Ass. nat., encore avec guill. si je me souviens bien, p.-ê. être utilisé pour marquer le fait que la personne ne peut employer le mot _mensonge_ dans ce contexte et qu'on appuie, mais c'est un cas bien particulier. C'est intéressant. Merci !